# How to sense off-idle in internal combustion engine?

Tags: automotive-engineering, engines

What is the simplest way to sense off-idle in an internal combustion engine?  I am currently focusing on roadgoing and tractor, but would like as general-case a solution as possible.  Priority is on simplicity, reliability, and durability.  It needs to switch nominal 12VDC when triggered, normally off.  And has to be very suitable for retrofit.

Answer (score 2):

In an engine with a mechanical throttle control, there is an idle-stop screw of some form. It ensures that the linkage returns to a specific location when the applied throttle is released. By the same token, a microswitch that is placed to be depressed when on-idle will close (on-circuit) when the throttle linkage commands power above idle.

Microswitches are found in many devices, from washing machines, microwave ovens, 3D printers and more. Reliability, precision and repeatability is high.